# MySQL update remote server from local server

Tags: mysql

I am after some advice please. I am no developer and outsource my work requirements to various freelancers. I have a specific requirement but due to my lack of skills I’m not quite sure what to ask for, hence my question here.

I have a system where i have several Raspberry Pi "drones" that collect data. These drones are all connected to the web and at present instantly send the data via a live feed direct to a MySQL server hosted at Amazon. This server is accessible via a static IP address.

Each drone is given a unique ID and the data collected is tagged with that ID so we know where it comes from.

The existing MySQL server collects and processes all this data and we have a website that displays the stats. Nothing really complicated and the current system works very well.

The issue i have is we occasionally have internet connection issues from the drones so i want to make the whole system more robust. When the drones do have a connection issue we lose data as the drone do not store anything which is what I want to resolve.

Just as a heads up… due to the data structure the drone will not write to a file, they have to feed direct to a MySQL server.

To resolve this issue my Plan is to have a MySQL server run on each RPI with the same table structure etc as the main server. Each RPI will write to its own local MySQL server and i then need that server to "update" the main server at Amazon. Please note the data will only ever be sent in this direction, it will never come from Amazon back to the drones. When the drone can communicate with the main server I would like the drone based MySQL server to communicate pretty much instantly ( or as close as i can get it ) but where there is an internet connection issue i need the drone to store its own data until the internet connection is restored at which point it will update the main server.

As i have said, i am no developer so i wouldn’t be undertaking this work myself but i would like to know what i need to ask for in order to get the right system.

If anyone can help i would appreciate some pointers. In addition if this is the type of work you could undertake please feel free to let me know and maybe we could talk further via PM, after all … someone needs to do it 

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a schedule update to the Amazon Database, using the programming language that you are already using or whatever, something that looks like:

```
While(gattering data){
   Store data into local MySQL 
   for(each record in local MySQL){
     if(there is internet){
       store record in remote MySQL
       optional: read remote record to check data was correctly stored
       delete record in local MySQL
     }else{
       break;
     }
   }
}
```